# Bash getting lines between two patterns and editing them

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have an output from a dumpsys command and I want to extract lines between two patterns, Wake Locks & newline. After I get those lines I need a specific string from them. Wake and Lock appear in the output more than once, but Wake Locks: size just once, so the first pattern could be `"Wake*Locks*size"`

The output looks something like this (theres many lines above and below this)

```
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=35647, pid=362505, ws=null)
#White space
```

I want the lines between "Wake Locks: size=*" and the next newline, in a format I can extract the pids from it. Maybe something like this:

```
for i in `dumpsys power | #Some way to get the desired lines#`; do
Temp=`echo $i | awk '{print $4}'`
$Temp #Assign var pid = number
kill -9 $pid
done
```

**UPDATE**

The updated code:

```
dumpsys power | 
sed -n '/Wake Locks: size=/,/^$/ p' |
sed -e 's/.*pid=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | 
while read pid; do
    kill -9 ${pid}
done
```

Comment: There are three PIDs in the lines you show.  Which one do you want?  Or, do you want all?

Comment: One pid from each line, so all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't have a match on the first line, sed will do (You can check the first line first).
First remove all lines before Wake Locks (and that line as well), continue with deleting everything from the first empty line in the remaining stream, and while you are already parsing, get the pid (with `(\` and `\)` you get a remembered string which value is printed with `\1`).

```
dumpsys power | sed -e '1,/Wake Locks: size=3/ d' \
                    -e '/^$/,$ d' \
                    -e 's/.*pid=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | while read pid; do
   echo "You want to kill ${pid}"
done
```

EDIT:
Sorry, sed can be used with the -n flag: `sed -n '/Wake Locks: size=3/,/^$/p'`.
So you can rewrite the code to the more natural

```
dumpsys power | 
   sed -n '/Wake Locks: size=3/,/^$/ p' |
   sed -e 's/.*pid=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | 
   while read pid; do
      echo "You want to kill ${pid}"
   done
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/Wake Locks: size=/{f=1} !NF{f=0} f' file
```

will give you

```
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=35647, pid=362505, ws=null)
```

if you need just the pid values (there are three, which one?)  You can try this

```
awk -v FS="[ ,]" 'f{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                       if($i~/pid=/) {
                           sub(/pid=/,"",$i);print $i
                        }
                   } 
/Wake Locks: size=/{f=1} 
                !NF{f=0}' file     
364345
323345
362505
```

**Explanation:** Set flag f with the pattern and unset when empty line (NF: # of fields = 0).  If flag is set iterate over fields and when matched pattern delete the pattern to leave the searched number).  Field separator set to space and comma to delete the suffix comma from the number with the default separator.  You can use the results in a `while read pid; do ... done < <(awk ...)` or piping to another script which can handle multi line input.

Comment: So I would have to write the output to a file and continue from there, or does pipeing work here too? Also can you add explanations for your answer, for future refrence.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the lines you wish to extract correctly, you can also accomplish the same with bash builtins (parameter expansion/substring extraction):

```
#!/bin/bash

## read from "$1" or stdin
[ -r "$1" ] && infile="$1" || infile=/dev/stdin

## check line beginnings for each line
while read -r line; do
    [ "${line%%:*}" = "Wake Locks" -o \
    "${line%% *}" = "WAKELOCK_NAME" -o \
    "${line%% *}" = "ANOTHER_WAKELOCK" -o \
    "${line%% *}" = "WAKELOCK_NAME" ] && echo "$line"
done < "$infile"

exit 0
```

Or using `grep` you can use a file containing the patterns you would like to match in your larger file and call `grep -f matchfile largefile`. A matchfile in this case could look like:

**grep pattern file**

```
$ cat dat/wakematch.txt
^Wake Locks:
^WAKELOCK_NAME
^ANOTHER_WAKELOCK
^WAKELOCK_NAME
```

**Test Input**

```
$ cat dat/wake.txt
junk and more junk

Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=35647, pid=362505, ws=null)
#White space

junk and more junk

Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=35647, pid=362505, ws=null)
#White space
```

**Use/Output - bash parameter expansion/substring extraction**

```
$ bash wakelock.sh dat/wake.txt
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)

$ bash wakelock.sh <dat/wake.txt
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
```

**Using grep**

```
$ grep -f dat/wakematch.txt dat/wake.txt
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
Wake Locks: size=3
WAKELOCK_NAME  'Term' (uid=93847, pid=364345, ws=null)
ANOTHER_WAKELOCK 'Term' (uid=9190247, pid=323345, ws=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using gawk**

```
gawk '{if($0~/Wake Locks:/){while( !($0~/^\n$/) && getline >=1){print gensub(/.*pid=([0-9]+).*/,"\\1",$0);}}};'
```

**output**

```
364345
323345
362505
```